# Spyder producing error on start-up: Terminal server could not be located at http://127.0.0.1:8071

Tags: spyder

When I run spyder, an error appears with the text "Terminal server could not be located at http://127.0.0.1:8071 (the address is a link, which if clicked DOES take me to a functioning web terminal), please restart spyder on debugging mode and open an issue with the contents of None and None files at [https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal/issues."](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-terminal/issues.%22)

Dismissing the error dialog box allows me to interact with the IDE as normal in most ways (changing code, viewing file structure, and using the IPython console), but attempts to run the program fail, and the console restarts the kernel much more frequently than I think is normal (I don't normally use the console much though, so I'm not sure about this behavior).

I don't know how to start spyder in debugging mode, and my googling attempts were overwhelmed by results about debugging python *in* spyder. From the github issues page, there's one post where someone is having a similar issue, though their error message includes file names instead of None. There are no fixes mentioned in the issue discussion. There is one comment at the bottom that says the issue in another user's case is "obviously due to the environment variable 'HTTP_PROXY' being set' - I was messing with my proxy settings before the error occurred, so it's possible that my issue is related to that error, but I really do not know how proxy settings work or why it matters in this case. I did try reinstalling to see if that resolved the issue, but there was no change.

In case it's relevant, I'm running spyder with anaconda on a windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ryan, I got that error as well, after setting up http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables.  Deleting the environment variables and restarting Spyder fixed the problem.

Also, to restart Spyder in debug mode:  see the command of that name under the File menu.

Thanks for your clues; they helped me get going :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error as well. After reading your and Ashley's post I just reset the proxy and fixed the problem. By the way you can still set the proxy with autodetect mode and script with proxy address, it works fine with Spyder, please refer to the pic. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNjAn.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).